# cx_Oracle how to set a CLOB member attribute on a PL/SQL Object Type?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have a PL/SQL `object` that I want to populate in Python and pass into a PL/SQL procedure.

PL/SQL Object Type:

```
CREATE TYPE t_foo (
    name VARCHAR2(10),
    data CLOB,
);
```

Python:

```
obj_type = conn.gettype('t_foo')
o = obj_type.newobject()

o.NAME = 'test'
# Raises NotSupportedError: Object_ConvertFromPython(): unhandled data type 112
o.DATA = 'big string' 

blobvar = cur.var(cx_Oracle.CLOB)
blobvar.setvalue(0, 'big string')
# Raises NotSupportedError: Object_ConvertFromPython(): unhandled data type 112
o.CONTENTS = blobvar
```

Is there any way to set a CLOB on an Object Type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for this has been added into the source for cx_Oracle which can be found here: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle. A release will follow in the next month or so but in the meantime you can build yourself from a cloned repository.